# @Preauthorize Spring Security dynamic

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I want to use `@Preauthorize` for dynamic endpoint

example.

```
v1/api/customer = unauthorize
v2/api/customer = @Preauthorize
```

I tried to use interface then override but its not working

Answer (score 0):

You can try with using @Preauthorize at service level than rest controller level